# Tender dossier with centered articles

Tags: horizontal-alignment, sectioning, indexing, article

I'm trying to write a tender dossier in LaTeX.

I'm trying to achieve the result in the picture below:

[image]

I need mainly to know 3 things:

- which would be the best class to use
  (article, book etc.)
- how to get the section-like 'Art. number' in the center of the page
  with the title below 'Definizione e Gerarchia ...'
- and finally how to get the proper index like in the picture

I was trying to use the titlesec package but I don't know if it is the proper way to do it and where to go from there.

```
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\normalfont\scshape\filcenter}%
{\thesection.}{1em}%
{Art. \arabic{section}}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you are using `\section` for articles, you should use `book`.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!